# How to disallow Perforce UNIX server to generate thousands of IDLE processes

Tags: unix, server, admin, perforce

Im' asking this question because we run out of ideas on how to handle the current situation of our perforce versioning server.

**The Server**

The server is hosted on Scaleway and has a baremetal machine with two SSD under the hood (we know it is no hardware issue).

We are currently using the free license of perforce to evaluate it.
P4 info yields the following:

[image]

**The Problem**

We are using perforce on a UNIX server to version our Unreal Engine 4 project. Lately we discovered that the server stockpiled an amount of 2771 processes where around 80% of them are p4d processes. We suspect these IDLE connections / processes to swamp the server and to be the root of the connectivity issues we encounter at the office.

We enabled monitoring to keep an eye on RUNNING and IDLE processes

```
p4 configure set monitoring=2
```

When we now display the monitored processes we see IDLE ones running for more than one hour

```
p4 monitor show
```

We already tried disabling leepalive connections with

```
p4 configure set net.keepalive.disable=1
```

And we see the following which is going on for a while
[image]

**The Question**

Now the question I want to ask is:

- Does anybody else ever has encountered this behaviour with a perforce server on UNIX?
- Does anybody knows how we can tell the server that we want to discard IDLE connections ?

EDIT

So after some tracking we discovered that the proxy our office network is behind causes the problems and for some reasons don't allow the connections to close. Does anyone has some clues how to get around these issue?

Comment: P4V and P4VS are designed to retain connections to the server for short periods of time (I think the default is 30 seconds or so, but it's configurable). Are the connections really all coming from one single IP address (195.245.224.246?) Is that a proxy or router of some sort? Or is it somebody's workstation?

Comment: Hey Bryan,
the connection are comming from one IP because the office we are at is in a network behind a proxy. So that's the proxys IP address the connection come from. Do you know any limitations of having clients behind a proxy talk to the P4 server ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the monitor output it appears that these clients are opening a bunch of connections and holding them open, basically DOSing the server.  You could go through and kill the pids on the server side, but this sounds like a bug in the client that should be raised with Perforce technical support.

Comment: As far as I could track it down I saw that the P4V clients and the P4VS plugins at the dev machines in the office cause this issue - I'm quite out of ideas because both are the latest versions from the Perforce homepage and we run a free license server without technical support

Comment: I'd try downgrading to an older version.  (FWIW when I used Perforce I generally avoided using either P4V or the VS plugin due to stability issues, although what you're describing sounds worse than average.)